# How can I isolate caller audio with sip or voip?

Tags: sip, voip, asterisk, twilio, freeswitch

I have a scenario that i'd like to implement, and don't know where to begin.

I'd like to have 3 participants on a phone call:  A, B and C.

A  and C should be able to talk to and hear each other.

B should be able to hear A, but not C.       B doesn't need to speak to anyone

Is there a way that I can implement this with SIP servers, freeswitch, asterisk or online services such as twilio/tropo?

Is there a name for such a scenario in telephony where you isolate the voices of one or more callers?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is known as call barge and is used in monitoring call center agents.

You can do it using the asterisk ChanSpy command:
http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+ChanSpy

Answer (score 1):

in FreeSWITCH, [eavesdropping](http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Misc._Dialplan_Tools_eavesdrop) works for the whole conversation. But as it's an open-source tool, you can probably modify sources for your needs.

Comment: sure, although it might turn out a bit too expensive :)  See www.k-open.com or skype:ssinyagin

Answer (score 1):

You can develop a conferencing application using [Call Control XML (CCXML)](http://www.w3.org/TR/ccxml/).  When you bring a caller on the conference you use the "[join" element](http://www.w3.org/TR/ccxml/#Join).  When you "join" the caller you can specify in the "duplex" tag whether it is full or half. If it is half then the caller can only hear what is going on and cannot speak.

A great platform for trying this out for free is [Voxeo's Prophecy](https://evolution.voxeo.com/). They have an excellent implementation of CCXML (their CTO is the Editor in Chief for this W3C standard) and you can try this hosted platform for free. You only pay when you put it into production. It supports SIP, Skype, and regular telephone lines.  You can even use their [Phono plugin](http://phono.com/) to create a phone in a web browser that users could use to join the conference. They also have an on-premise solution that is easy to install on a laptop or server and they give you two ports for free. Additional ports are reasonably priced. There are a lot of examples on developing CCXML conferencing applications in [their documentation](http://docs.voxeo.com/ccxml/1.0-final/).

Comment: Not really but please contact by mail (appears on ivrworx page) with what you are trying to achive.

Answer (score 1):

try ivrworx,

you can firstly create freeswitch conference.

Thean make scripts which will call the conference but C will send SDP  with rcvonly attribute